# Метод filter не работает с Html элементами

Tags: javascript, html, filter

```js
// Этот код работает
let elements = $('.item');
console.log(elements);

let newElements = elements.filter(function() {
 return $(this).attr('class') === 'item third';
});
console.log(newElements);




// Этот код не работает
let elements = $('.item');
console.log(elements);

let newElements = elements.filter(function(item) {
 return item.attr('class') === 'item third';
});
console.log(newElements);
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item third">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item">5</li>
</ul>
```

Почему при обращении к массиву элементов с помощью динамически созданной переменной "item" внутри метода "filter", не работает метод "attr" для этой переменной "item"?

Comment: Почему при обращении к массиву элементов с помощью динамически созданной переменной "item" внутри метода "filter", не работает метод "attr" для этой переменной "item". Буду благодарен ответу

Comment: Метку лучше добавлять сразу jQuery. так как у вас не просто js, а использование библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из [документации](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) `return item.attr('class') === 'item third';` не работает из за того что первый аргумент callback item является индексом, а не элементом.

Вам нужно или так:

```
var elements = jQuery(".item"),
newElements = elements.filter(function(index, element) {
    return element.className == "item third";
});
console.log(newElements);
```

Или так что ещё лучше:

```
var elements = jQuery(".item"), 
    newElements = elements.filter(".third");
console.log(newElements);
```

A так как this у callback является текущим элементом в итерации (или рекурсии), сравнение `$(this).attr('class') === 'item third';` и работает.